# How to create a plugin GUI for QGIS 2.8.2?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-2.8

I create a pluging with the pluging builder in Qgis 2.8.2. I went to the folder of my pluging : C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\yu in order to visualize al the files that the pluging builder created. After i launch the OSGeo4w batch file, in order to create the .ui file of my pluging by using the command:

```
pyuic4 -o ....
```

Here's the error that i have:
[image]

Comment: The error and what you enter exactly would be very helpful

Comment: The errror : No such file or directory....

Comment: You posed a new question as an answer to this one so I have converted it into an edit.  Would you be able to use the **edit** button to keep it as one question that is in sync with the existing answer, please?  If it should have been a new question then you should perhaps accept the answer that has been given here and then ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The pyuic4 command generates .py files from .ui files - not the other way round.

.ui files are created with QtDesigner and define the graphical user interface of your application.

As they are not directly usable with python, you have to either convert them to python files first or load them with a [QUiLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/quiloader.html).

Comment: C:\>pyuic4 -o "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\yu\ui_yu.ui" "C:\OSGeo4W64\
apps\qgis\python\plugins\yu\yu.py"
Error in input file: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1